# Firebase Performance Monitoring React Native integration

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-performance

I have install Firebase Performance monitoring on my React Native app
and integrate it successfully. After i want to track my network requests performance and go through as documentation.

```
const trackRequest = async (url,method) => {
    // Define the network metric
    const metric = await perf().newHttpMetric(url, method);

    // Define meta details
    metric.putAttribute('testAttr', 'testValue');

    // Perform a HTTP request and provide response information
    const response = await fetch(url);
    metric.setHttpResponseCode(response.status);
    metric.setResponseContentType(response.headers.get('Content-Type'));
    metric.setResponsePayloadSize(response.headers.get('Content-Length'));

    // Stop the trace
    await metric.stop();

    return response.json();
};
```

I use this function from documentation and call it every network requests time

```
fetch("www.example.com")
trackRequest("www.example.com","GET")
```

Can anyone explain me what i were doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the API correctly.  There appears to be a good example in the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/perf-mon/example#Network-Metric).  You need to call `start()` on the metric before calling `stop()`.  Also, the example shows that you should use await on each method call, but I don't really know if that's necessary.

```
const trackRequest = async (url,method) => {
    const metric = await perf().newHttpMetric(url, method);

    // !!! Don't forget to call start()
    await metric.start();

    await metric.putAttribute('testAttr', 'testValue');

    const response = await fetch(url);

    await metric.setHttpResponseCode(response.status);
    await metric.setResponseContentType(response.headers.get('Content-Type'));
    await metric.setResponsePayloadSize(response.headers.get('Content-Length'));

    // Stop the trace only after you started it
    await metric.stop();

    return response.json();
};
```

Comment: i use https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/perf/quick-start#http-request-tracing example, and there are not any lines about `start()`

Comment: The example looks wrong to me.  Use whatever actually works.  The Firebase official docs say to call start on other client OS, and I'm certain the API doesn't really change for react: https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/https_traces#add-custom-https-requests